# Email to ask for work

Tags: work-environment, teamwork, work-time, work-life

I have recently joined a software company and I have to write an email to my counter part asking him to assign me some work in my project.i have never dealt with him before and I am struggling as to how can I write an email to him. Need thoughts and suggestions on this.

Comment: What is making you struggle, exactly? We can't word an email for you, but it sounds like "Hi, can you assign me some tasks?" is pretty much the extent of what you need to write.

Comment: @Erik since I have not dealt with him before. Should I directly send an email to him as you mentioned. Or should I add some introduction about my work experience and etc. That's where I am struggling

Comment: Is this team in remote?  Why are you sending an email to a team member, who presumably, is in the same office as yourself?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to detail your whole life history here above a few basics.

Simply put:

> Hi Bob, I'm a new team member here and I've been told to ask you to assign me some work items.  Could you please assign some work items to me and point me toward any relevant documentation. FYI, I've had x years experience in

It does seem a bit strange that you've not been introduced (even via email) to your team by your manager/lead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been introduced via an email you a very long list of people though.

Comment: I think the last bit is too much info. I would just ask for work and if anything irrelevant comes in you can discuss your experiences in whatever matter.

Answer (score 4):

While Snow's answer is correct, I would go a little further.

Rather than write and ask for work, write and ask for a chat to discuss what work you should do.

As you mentioned, telling him your experience might be helpful.

More importantly, you want a discussion of the project (and the documentation is ***never*** complete, correct or up to date).

If you meet, he can give an overview of the project, which will help you understand your place in it. Chatting also gives you a chance to ask questions, or ask for clarifications, and as you do - and especially at the end - you should summarize what you think you have understood and ask if that is correct. It would take along time to do that by a series of emails.

You say that you are new to the company, but not if you are new to the industry. As a contractor of *cough* decades, I occasionally get told where the code base is and given a bunch of problem reports to solve, but 90% of the time it is a thirty minute chat about the project followed by a large bundle of documents to read and that seems about right for any new project.

So, by all means send an email (personally, I might seek him out in person to introduce myself, which almost inevitably leads to a chat), but don't ask for work - ask for a chat.

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree with this @Mawg (lol sorry to disagree with you twice in a row!)  In the go-go world of software nobody wants a long chat ... or even a short chat.  Just keep it absolutely to the point, in a matter of seven or eight words state that you are absolutely ready to go and will do anything the lead says - and you'll do it quickly.  I suggest to the OP reversing your paragraph[5] - get the facts and it will probably come with a pile of PDFs.  Then it may lead to a chat.

Comment: err, para 6 for humans

Comment: Lolx - are you in "new fangled" stuff, like web-based? I am in embedded, where we realize that "investing" 30 minutes in a chat to clarify things saves much more time than explaining it by email later. Don't ever buy into "we don't have time to" - whether it is writing documentation, code review, unit test, or taking 30 minutes to on-board the new guy - in my experience, every time I heard this we didn't have time NOT to :-)

Comment: that's really funny man.  I was about to say "however, at the moment we're doing a low-level job with devices and when you do actual *work* like that it involves weeks of discussion and planning"  :)  startup / app crap is more just "get it the hell done. just get anything done so we can get more money from fool investors"  :)

Comment: Ha ha. Still, the new start is a resource & you have to put soem time in to get some value out